# Ember JS Router Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

This is my router

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('index', { path: '/' });
    this.route('EnterExpense', { path: '/TABA' });
    this.route('Compute', { path: '/TABB' });
});
```

When I am in url/TABB on click of a button i show a table using Jquery as -[image]

When i move to TABA and again come back to TABB the table disappears.I have to click the button showsummary to bring it back.Is there any way to show the table  after  migrating from Tabb(where first time i will click the button to generate table) to Taba and again Tabb(the previous generated table should show now)

Comment: why do you have the same path for two different routes?

Comment: the paths are different

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. It looks like you need to nest the route and have the table on the parent route.

Comment: Can you show us how you are generating the table?

Comment: I m new to ember so as of now I m just using jquery    append function like $("#div). Append("<table..)  Is this a bad practice to play with jquery in the dom?

Comment: So reason why I think you're not seeing the table is because you're appending the generated table to the view and the view gets destroyed when you navigate away so when you navigate back it's a brand new view.  The ember way would be to create a new nested route for the table.